# Issue with fillText

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am writing code for game.

`strokeText()` work fine but `fillText()` doesn't work:

```
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, " + alpha + ")";
context.font = "italic 20pt Arial";
context.fillText(text, tx, ty);
```

Comment: Theoretically, `fillText` and `strokeText` should work the same. Could you provide a working sample?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Is it just not displaying? If so, it could be helpful to see the values for tx, ty and alpha.

Comment: no error  displayed just nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this to test if it works:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("Hello World!", 10, 50);
```

If so, change the values to your variables.

For try example:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_filltext

Comment: Not W3Schools, please.